# How to create a function in Jquery that affects the selected div

Tags: jquery, html, function, select

My objective is to create a function for a select that when is changed it changes the placeholder in an input. I've done that.

But my problem is making the function valid for any new input+select that I add. And doing it so I don't have to create a new function with new id's everytime. I need a global function that affects only what I'm clicking.

(In the end I'm adding a button to create new forms, so I need the global function to work with any new form the user creates)

- This is the html form in Bootstrap (Im reducing the code to the essential)

```
<div id="form">

  <input name="telefono" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Móvil">

  <select>
    <option value="Móvil">Móvil</option>
    <option value="Casa">Casa</option>
    <option value="Trabajo">Trabajo</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

- This is the function in jQuery

```
$(function(){   
  $("#form").find("select").change(function(){
    $("#form").find("input").attr("placeholder", $(this).find(":selected").val());
  });
});
```

Using this code I can change the first div form that I create but not the new ones.

I'm using Bootstrap for the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code. hope it will work.

```
$(function(){   
  $(document).on("change", "select", function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var parent = $(this).closest("#form");
            parent.find("input").attr("placeholder",selectedValue);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To have your function work with all dynamically added `select` and `input` elements, you have to pass the `change()` event from a parent element that's already there when the page is initially loaded to the `select` elements using `on()`:

```
$(function(){   
  $(document).on("change", "select", function(){
     $(this).prev("input").attr("placeholder", $(this).find(":selected").val());
  }); 
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL58g7ck/)
[jQuery on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, it works. I just forgot that I had each my input and my button in a div. So when I use this function it doesn´t find the previous input

Comment: @cicb When you add a new input and select, do you add them to the div with the id="form" or are you adding them in a new div as well? Actually the code in my answer targets the input that is the previous element of the changed select, maybe your changed html looks different.

Comment: When I add new inputs and select I add them each in a new div and both divs in another one. It's kinda weird, but with the Bootstrap cols I found this the best way. Until I'll have to change it again tomorrow because I need to add a sortable ul. Thank you so much for your answer and it definetly works, but currently I'm not sure what path to take with the entire project (and I'm new into js and jquery)